# "Дядюшка Сэм"

Tags: фразеология

"Дядюшка Сэм" — в советское время это стало нарицательным для обозначения "американского капиталиста". Он имел вполне конкретное изображение. А кто стал прототипом? Откуда вообще пошло это выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас уже никто точно не сможет сказать, каким образом мифический дядюшка» появился на свет»,однако, наиболее распространенная, но фактически недоказанная, версия возникновения Дяди Сэма носит мифологический характер и заключается в следующей американской легенде.

Во время войны 1812 года Сэмюэл Уилсон, бизнесмен из города Трой, штат Нью-Йорк, со своим коллегой Альбертом Андерсеном, поставляли для американской армии провизию в бочонках. Бочонки были помечены соответственно буквами « U . S .», сокращением от United States , и среди американских солдатов распространилась шутка о щедром герое Дяде Сэме ( Uncle Sam ). В 1961 году 87-й Конгресс США принял резолюцию, в которой Сэмюэл Уилсон официально признавался прототипом образа Дяди Сэма.

Историческая несправедливость – ни одного подлинного портрета Сэмюэля Уилсона до наших времен не сохранилось. Зато осталась вполне ухоженная могила на одном из нью-йоркских кладбищ, где на большом сером камне установлена мемориальная табличка, свидетельствующая, что именно здесь нашел свой последний приют Сэмюэль Уилсон. Он прожил довольно продолжительную жизнь и не дотянул до своего 80-летия только два года.

Падкие до праздников американцы отмечают 13 марта (именно в этот день появилось первое графическое изображение образа Дядюшки Сэма), как День Дядюшки Сэма.
Более подробно читайте здесь http://www.lingvaflavor.com/dyadya-sem-istoriya-personaga